# Lazy MyBatis 3 no funciona bien

Tags: java, mybatis

Estoy usando en mybatis 3.0, para poder ejecutar unas consultas muy grandes he cambiado la configuración para que consulte la información cuando se recorra el objeto.

La configuración es la siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<configuration>

    <settings>
        <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="true"/>
        <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <setting name="aggressiveLazyLoading" value="false"/>
        <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="NULL" />
        <setting name="localCacheScope" value="STATEMENT"/>
        <setting name="autoMappingBehavior" value="FULL"/>
    </settings>
    ...
```

Ahora dos beans para guardar la información:

Clase Persona:

```
public class Persona {

    private String                     nombre;
    private String                     id_persona;

    private List<Registros>            registrosPersona;


    //getter and setter

}
```

Clase Registros:

```
public class Registros {

    private Date                       fecha;
    private String                     id_persona;



    //getter and setter

}
```

Por último el mapeo con las consultas a la bbdd.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.mapper.xml.Consultas">

    <resultMap id="personasMap" type="com.bean.Persona">
        <result property="nombre"            column="NOMBRE"/>
        <result property="id_persona"        column="ID_PERSONA"/>

        <association property="registrosPersona"      select="com.mapper.xml.Consultas.findRegistrosPersona"  column="{id_persona=ID_PERSONA}"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="findPersonas" resultMap="personasMap">
        Select nombre, id_persona 
        from PERSONAS
    </select>



    <resultMap id="registrosPersonaMap" type="com.bean.Registros">
        <result property="fecha"             column="FECHA"/>
        <result property="id_persona"        column="ID_PERSONA"/>
    </resultMap

    <select id="findRegistrosPersona" resultMap="registrosPersonaMap">
        Select fecha, id_persona
        from REGISTROS
    </select>
</mapper>
```

Entonces ahora viene el problema, ejecuto lo siguiente y el objeto `registrosPersona` no tiene ningún valor (existiendo valores en bbdd):

```
List<Personas> lista = sqlMap.selectList("findPersonas");

for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++ ) {
    Persona p = lista.get(i);
    for(int j=0; j<p.getRegistrosPersona().size(); j++ ) {
        System.out.println( p.getRegistrosPersona().get(j).getFecha()   );
    }
}
```

Pero si copio el código 2 veces:

List lista = sqlMap.selectList("findPersonas");

```
for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++ ) {
    Persona p = lista.get(i);
    for(int j=0; j<p.getRegistrosPersona().size(); j++ ) {
        System.out.println( p.getRegistrosPersona().get(j).getFecha()   );
    }
}
//Aqui pinta el System.out.println
for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++ ) {
    Persona p = lista.get(i);
    for(int j=0; j<p.getRegistrosPersona().size(); j++ ) {
        System.out.println( p.getRegistrosPersona().get(j).getFecha()   );
    }
}
```

¿Esto porqué pasa? Es como que no le da tiempo a hacer la consulta.

Comment: Cuando se usan result sets multiples este atributo especifica las columnas (separadas por comas) que se correlarán con las indicadas en foreignColumn para identificar al padre y e hijo de una relación.
[Manual de referencia](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/es/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps#Result_Maps)

Comment: Además de que en la etiqueta association te falta el atributo resultSet

Answer (score 3):

Si tu problema realmente ocurre a causa de el tiempo de espera, existe, según la documentación, la propiedad `defaultStatementTimeout` que determina (mediante un numero entero) la cantidad de segundos que el sistema espera una respuesta de la base de datos

```
  <setting name="defaultStatementTimeout" value="25"/>
```

Comment: lo probaré, si es eso te acepto la respuesta, gracias.

Comment: He probado a ejecutar esas consultas con un tiempo de 120 segundos pero no carga toda la información de la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando personasMap como identificador en ambos casos.

```
<resultMap id="personasMap" type="com.bean.Persona">
<resultMap id="personasMap" type="com.bean.Registros">
```

Prueba a usar identificadores distintos, a ver si te funciona:

```
<resultMap id="personasMap" type="com.bean.Persona">
<resultMap id="registrosPersonaMap" type="com.bean.Registros">
```

Comment: Ha sido un error al pegar el código.